# Accessing my local scope from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to play around with some JS in the Chrome console but after having dragged-and-dropped my local folder I still cannot access my methods and the rest of my functions/variables.
How can I change the scope to get access to them?

Here's an image of the "undefined" errors I have

[image]

Comment: Have you loaded `to_do_list.js` from the HTML file?

Comment: Are you trying to 'run' your javascript in Chrome without a HTML? You can do it with 'Console' Tab... not with fileSystem module. The FileSystem will bind original files (in you workspace) with the content registered in the page (a html openned). See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/sources

Comment: Hi guys, thank you both for your input.
@Barmar : I haven't no, only working in the console right now so no linking yet.

Comment: @PedroRamon: I am not using an HTML file. I do have a few web tabs open but I don't think that would be the cause? I have tried running my command in the console tab and in a "drawer" with the console within the network tab, to no avail...

Comment: Viewing a .js file in the browser doesn't execute it, it just displays the source code. You have to load it from a .html file.

Comment: @Barmar : thanks, that cured it!

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot seems that you are not paused in any breakpoint, if you want to inspect the scope of a function you need to pause the code execution with a breakpoint in the part of the code that you want to see the scope.